# How to start with a clean db every day?

Tags: php, mysql

Iv'e got a site which alows users to submit a form on the startpage. When the form is submitted it goes to database and outputs to a div on the startpage.

I wonder if I can reset mysql automaticly on a daily basis so the start page is clean every morning.

Comment: Usually , it's better to clean tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into phpMyAdmin in SQL command line

```
CREATE EVENT delete_class_data

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY

DO

DELETE FROM `name here`
```

Further information here:

http://www.infotuts.com/schedule-sql-query-using-phpmyadmin-mysql-events/

Answer (score 0):

**I'll recommend Shane's answer above. But if you need to do this with PHP. Try this:**

You'll have to do this with CRON jobs. You might now have this on your server. So what you can do is to run a script when the first user of the day visits your website. What I'd suggest:

Create a table or record in your database which saves today's date.
Let's say it saved the date "12-03-2015"

Now, when the user visits your website. It runs the script: today.php. With contents:

```
$q = "SELECT today_date FROM date_table;";
$r = mysqli_query($q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($r);
$last_date = $row['today_date']

$current_date = date('d-m-o');

if ($last_date == $current_date) {
    // do nothing, because the current date is already saved, so there was an user before this user, who already runned this script
} else {
    // erase the database and insert the new data in the record
}
```